# Variavel is not defined (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, funções, onclick

```
function RemoverForro(valor){
   var valorForro = valor;
}

$(add_button7).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(l < max_fields7){
          l++;
          $(wrapper7).append(
            '<div id="tipo_forro_div_'+ l +'" class="input-group margin">'+
            '<div id="tipo_forro_nome_'+ l +'"></div>'+
              '<div class="input-group-btn">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" onclick="RemoverForro('+ l +')" href="#">Remover</button>'+
              '</div>'+
              '&emsp;<select name="forro_tipo'+ l +'" id="forro_tipo'+ l +'" required style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 20px" onchange ="exibir_ocultar_forro(this, '+ l +')">'+
                      '<option value="">Selecione</option>'+
                      '<option value="1">Gesso (Placas)</option>'+
                      '<option value="2">Gesso Acartonado</option>'+
                      '<option value="3">Fibra Mineral</option>'+
                      '<option value="4">Laje</option>'+
                      '<option value="0">Outros</option>'+
                  '</select>'+
                  '<div id="outros_forro'+ l +'" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 15px; font-size: 14px"><input id="outros_forro'+ l +'" type="text"  placeholder="Especifique" name= "outros_forro'+ l +'"/></div>'+
                  '<input type="text" style= "width: 21%; margin-left: 15px; font-size: 14px" name="forro_qtd'+ l +'" id= "forro_qtd'+ l +'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>'+
              '</div>'); //add input box
      }


$(wrapper7).on("click","#delete", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); document.getElementById("tipo_forro_div_"+ valorForro).remove(); l--; <?= $l--?>
  })
```

Ai quando aperta no botão de remover aparece o erro "valorForro is not defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ela de fato não está...

Veja que `valorForro`, está restrito ao escopo do método `RemoverForro(valor)`, assim como `l`e `max_fields7` ao `$(add_button7).click()`, embora nesse caso elas nem foram declaradas...

```
function RemoverForro(valor){
   var valorForro = valor;
}
```

E você está tentando acessá-la a partir de:

```
$(wrapper7).on("click","#delete", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); document.getElementById("tipo_forro_div_"+ valorForro).remove(); l--; <?= $l--?>
  })
```

Para "corrigir" você pode declarar e inicializar fora do método e apenas alterar seu valor de acordo com as condições.

```
var valorForro = null;

function RemoverForro(valor){
   valorForro = valor;
}

$(add_button7).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(l < max_fields7){
          l++;
          $(wrapper7).append(
            '<div id="tipo_forro_div_'+ l +'" class="input-group margin">'+
            '<div id="tipo_forro_nome_'+ l +'"></div>'+
              '<div class="input-group-btn">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" onclick="RemoverForro('+ l +')" href="#">Remover</button>'+
              '</div>'+
              '&emsp;<select name="forro_tipo'+ l +'" id="forro_tipo'+ l +'" required style="width: 25%; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 20px" onchange ="exibir_ocultar_forro(this, '+ l +')">'+
                      '<option value="">Selecione</option>'+
                      '<option value="1">Gesso (Placas)</option>'+
                      '<option value="2">Gesso Acartonado</option>'+
                      '<option value="3">Fibra Mineral</option>'+
                      '<option value="4">Laje</option>'+
                      '<option value="0">Outros</option>'+
                  '</select>'+
                  '<div id="outros_forro'+ l +'" style="display: none; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 15px; font-size: 14px"><input id="outros_forro'+ l +'" type="text"  placeholder="Especifique" name= "outros_forro'+ l +'"/></div>'+
                  '<input type="text" style= "width: 21%; margin-left: 15px; font-size: 14px" name="forro_qtd'+ l +'" id= "forro_qtd'+ l +'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>'+
              '</div>'); //add input box
      }


$(wrapper7).on("click","#delete", function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); document.getElementById("tipo_forro_div_"+ valorForro).remove(); l--; <?= $l--?>
});
```